# like '%M' not working for character datatype PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, char, varchar

like '%' works as expected for varchar datatype and not works for char datatype in PostgreSQL.

Created a table as below in PostgreSQL:
`create table movie(movie_name varchar(20), director char(20));`
[Note: movie_name is varchar type and director is char type]
and inserted few rows using the below query.

```
insert into movie values('JaiBhim', 'Gnanavel');

insert into movie values('Dharbar', 'ARM');
```

After this, I used the below select query with '%'.

```
select * 
from movie 
where movie_name like '%m';
```

I got correct row details. [JaiBhim and Gnanavel].

I used another select query with '%' as below.

```
select * 
from movie 
where director like '%M';
```

For this I expected one row should be returned but it returned 0 rows.

For varchar, 'like %' gives correct result and for char datatype it is not giving.

Is it the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes. Read [Character types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-character.html): *character(n), char(n)  fixed-length, blank padded*. The `%M` is not taking into account the spaces after the `M` , try `%M%` or `select * from movie where trim(director) like '%M'

Comment: [Don't use char](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_char.28n.29)

Answer (score 0):

`character` pads the values with blanks, so a pattern `'%M'` will only match a `character(10)` if the tenth character is an `M`.

The best solution is to avoid `character` and use `character varying` instead, like the documentation recommends. Other than that, you could use a regular expression:

```
WHERE movie_name ~ 'M *$'
```